# Temperatures for AMD A10 6800K APU?

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature, integrated-graphics

I have **AMD A10 6800K**, which is APU(is a CPU with GPU included) and I wonder what are the safe temps for the **WHOLE** package, I don't if I'm mistaking or not.

I know the **ideal temperature** for AMD A10-6800K is **74Cº**. Is 74Cº for the CPU or the whole **APU**?

My normal **temperatures** for(**the max shows when I'm playing**):

CPU:

Max- 70Cº 
Min- 44Cº(when idle)

GPU:
Max- 40Cº
Min- 8Cº(when idle)

whole APU:
Max- 113Cº
Min- 62Cº

[image]

I'm using the heatsink and cooler that came with the APU and another cooler from the case Cooler Master K350.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google `hwmonitor package temperature` there are loads of people [reporting](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140226070131AATJmUA) similar anomalous readings. So it seems like HWMonitor doesn't report temperatures correctly for some CPU's.

It may be worth trying [Aida64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads) (commercial with 30 day trial) or [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) (freeware) to compare readings as some people have reported getting more accurate readings from them.

But either way the readings in your screenshot can't possibly be correct as your PC would have shut down or crashed long before the CPU reached 113ºC.